# Confused about why PowerShell Core has to be installed on Windows...?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

So I've just read a lengthy explanation of the difference between PowerShell and PowerShell Core. Basically, the latter is the new name for all future versions of PowerShell, and it's now open source and cross-platform.

Alright. Good. But why does it have to be *installed* on Windows? Wouldn't the point be that it's already on Windows, but then you can also install it on Linux/macOS and use it the same way as on Windows?

Why is it an "installation" even on Windows? That part makes no sense to me. And it can't be explained by "it's just released", because it's apparently been several *years* already...

Comment: Because _Windows PowerShell_ is not the same thing as _PowerShell Core_.

Comment: Windows PowerShell is a Windows component. PowerShell Core is a different product

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no more PowerShell. All future versions are called PowerShell Core. That's why I asked the question. It's the premise of my ponder. As you did in my other question, you reply with comments that seem to disregard what I typed in the question...

Comment: They're still sticking with PS 5 in Windows, because it has a lot more commands, until PS 7.  You can install both.  PS 6 is even portable.

Comment: This may provide some pointers: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/the-next-release-of-powershell-powershell-7/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell Core is the new Universal Powershell.

Windows Comes with "Windows Powershell" which was the predecessor to Powershell core and only runs on windows, and uses methods that are windows .net specific, instead of using the portable.net methods.

Powershell Core is being actively developed and enhanced, and is able to be run on Windows and Linux systems, but does not contain the Windows-specific methods as it is intended to be cross-platform, which leads to some incompatibilities.

Rather than continue to build and maintain separate flavors of Powershell in perpetuity, the Windows Powershell 5.1 functions will eventually fold into PowerShell core at some point  in the future (possibly as early as version 7.0), and deprecated methods will need to be re-written to use the universal functions.

Last I read on this Redmond had predicted that Powershell Core 7.0 will essentially usurp the needs for Powershell 5.1 on Windows and will start being the pre-installed version of Powershell in Windows at some point thereafter.  (So Probably Windows 2022 for Server folks)